# Para que serve o código /** na linguagem java?

Tags: java

Enquanto eu mexia no *netbeans* usando linguagem *java* não entendi para que servia esse comando `/**` , fui atrás e apareceu alguma coisa sobre *Javadoc*, não entendi bem o que isso queria dizer alguém poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Para inserir comentários no código-fonte, em Java, pode-se utilizar uma de duas formas:

```
// Comentário em uma única linha

/* Comentário
   que se divide em várias
   linhas
 */
```

Quando se escreve comentários da forma (note os dois asteriscos na primeira linha)

```
/**
 *
 */
```

Os comentários podem ser interpretados por uma ferramenta - chamada [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html) - que gera uma documentação baseada no código-fonte utilizando, além dos comentários entre `/** */`,  outras anotações especiais, como `@author` e `@date`, que fornecem, respectivamente, informações de autoria e a data de criação do arquivo.

O artigo da [wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) fornece uma boa noção sobre Javadoc.

A [API do Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) é um exemplo de documentação gerada utilizando-se a ferramenta.

Comment: então esse comando serve apenas para comentar mais que uma linha?

Comment: @Nicolas Editei a resposta dando mais detalhes

Comment: Interessante notar que o `/**` é um mero `/*`, o * a mais é apenas parte do texto "comentado", e é ignorado pelo Java como qualquer outro caractere que está dentro do comment, até que se encontre um `*/` . Ou seja, o 'pessoal" do Javadoc poderia ter escolhido `/*#`, `/*{` ou mesmo `/*JD`, tanto faz o caractere, desde que seja dentro de um comment de várias linhas (ou seja, começado por `/*`).

Answer (score 2):

Complementando, seguem algumas tags:

- {@code} todo texto dentro das chaves não é interpretado, incluindo
  texto com marcação HTML e tags Java
- {@docRoot} contém o diretório raiz da documentação gerada
- @deprecated indica que o arquivo ou método está obsoleto, descontinuado, portanto não é indicado o seu uso
- @exception serve para indicar os possíveis exceções
- @throws serve para indicar os possíveis lançamentos
- {@link} faz refência (link) à outra documentação de algum metodo
- @param serve para descrever parâmetros
- {@value} contém o valor de uma constante
- @version especifica a versão atual da classe ou interface
- @since especifica a versão em que o método foi incluido